# how can i configure .htaccess file for this?

Tags: php, .htaccess

My link as below(index.php):

```
<a href="http://localhost/example-link.html">Example Link</a>
```

or maybe my link as below:

```
<a href="http://localhost/other.html">Other</a>
```

When click to the link I want to get "example-link.html" ır "other.html" from **cat.php**

Cat.php

```
<?php 
echo $_GET["cat"];
?>
```

I want to print $_GET["cat"] (example-link.html or other.html)

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. Please explain clearly your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ cat\.php
```

> I want to print $_GET["cat"] (example-link.html or other.html)

The predefined variable `$_SERVER` will contain some of that information, perhaps the `REQUEST_URI`

Comment: I think you don't understand. example-link.html is for only example :) (in a sense variable)

Comment: Why don't you make your questions more comprehendible so people can answer it fully to the best of their knowledge?

Comment: See edited answer. full spec on http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I can see only "Internal Server Error"

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ cat\.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Redirect old file path to new file path
Redirect /example-link.html http://localhost/cat.php
```